# AutoNumber ID in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, auto-increment

What to do when the data is inserted in the database, the "ID" column is autonumber.
I tried this:

```cs
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int IdMema { get; set; }
public string Autor { get; set; }
public int? Like { get; set; }
public int? Dislike { get; set; }
```

Properties "Memy" table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Memy] (
    [Id_mema] INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [autor]   TEXT NULL,
    [like]    INT  NULL,
    [dislike] INT  NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_mema] ASC)
);
```

When I try to insert data, then I see:

> "SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Memy' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

How to resolve this?

Comment: the reason is you haven't set `auto increment` in your id column.

Comment: the message says **when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF**

Comment: how set auto inrement in id column?

Comment: I want enable auto increment

Comment: @kamilm758 if recreating table is an easy option than just delete the table and re run `create` query with this change `[Id_mema] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: can u share your insert code?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi It is auto-increment PK already ( IDENTITY, PRIMARY KEY)

Answer (score 1):

You have auto-increment field `Id_mema`. Auto-increment is set with [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) keyword. Exception says it:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Memy' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

When you insert data to your table, you cannot give value to identity field. DB engine gives value to `Id_mema`-field (auto-increment 0,1,2,3..)

Following should work (straight sql):

```
INSERT INTO MEMY(autor, like, dislike) values ('text',1,0)
```

and in case of entity framework, be sure not to set `Id_mema` in your code.

Comment: but the OP hasn't set ID column to be auto increment, I'm confused what value would be stored in case of query you provided.

Comment: It is auto-increment! `[Id_mema] INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY` and PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `Id_mema` value when you going to insert values like below.

```
INSERT INTO MEMY values ('kamilm',10,5);
```

OR

if you don't want to auto incremented column then change the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` it will allow you to insert value in Id(Key) column.

```
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
 public int IdMema { get; set; }
 public string Autor { get; set; }
 public int? Like { get; set; }
 public int? Dislike { get; set; }
```